# Bus schedules in Israel

Tags: buses, israel, maps, timetables

I'm looking for paper or pdf schedules of isreali bus routes (that i can use with out internet coverage)
i found for the golan routes http://www.golanbus.co.il/Files/art_files/lozhdash72017.pdf
but im having trouble finding for the other bus companies
i do read hebrew so that helps

Comment: It seems like all companies have schedules on their sites, but you must choose the line number to get the info. I don't see a way to get all lines in one file.

Answer (score 3):

No such PDF schedules currently exist, at least none that are up to date. You are therefore recommended to either write down the times in advance or buy a local SIM card to allow yourself to be permanently connected. I have traveled in the Golan Heights this year and connectivity was generally great.